QGIS file format for vector data on unstructured triangular mesh
I have a dataset of ocean currents on a triangular mesh from SCHISM model output that I am trying to write in a format that QGIS can visualize. For scalar variables, I have been able to write .2dm files that include the node coordinates, mesh topology, and data values (on the nodes), but I can't figure out how to write vector data that includes a u and v component. I have seen this question which is addressing the same topic, but their format seems to only work for rectangular and not triangular meshes. I know there are file formats out there that can hold this type of data that QGIS should be able to read, but I can't find an example file which I could model off of to help me write my own.
